# Elixir Phoenix recursive function stops page loading

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am building web app using Phoenix elixir where my web app needs to load a index page and than to wait in background for receiving message. This is my code where I have problem

```
defmodule ApplicationB.PageController do
  use ApplicationB.Web, :controller
  use AMQP

  def index(conn, _params) do
    {:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open
    {:ok, channel} = AMQP.Channel.open(connection)
    AMQP.Queue.declare(channel, "hello")
    AMQP.Basic.consume(channel, "hello", nil, no_ack: true)
    IO.puts " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C, CTRL+C"

    wait_for_messages

    render conn, "index.html"
  end

  def wait_for_messages do
    receive do
      {:basic_deliver, payload, _meta} ->
        IO.puts " [x] Received #{payload}"
        ApplicationB.Endpoint.broadcast! "message", "hello", %{body: "poruka"}
        wait_for_messages
    end
  end

end
```

I know that my problem is inside my wait_for_messages function because when I call wait_for_messages inside index it is recursive function and it never reach `render conn, "index.html"` line. Is there any way to make it works, so that page inde.html can be loaded and wait_for_messages to be running in background?

Comment: The simplest way would be to use `spawn` or `spawn_link` (http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#spawn/1) but I'm not posting this as an answer as the right way usually is to use a Supervisor somewhere to handle errors, possibly using `Task.Supervisor` for simple cases.

Comment: But if I use spawn or spawn_link is also stop my page content loading and just run function in background

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the [Task](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Task.html) module.

To prevent wait_for_messages/0 from blocking your action, you may use `Task.start_link/1` like this:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  {:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open
  {:ok, channel} = AMQP.Channel.open(connection)
  AMQP.Queue.declare(channel, "hello")
  AMQP.Basic.consume(channel, "hello", nil, no_ack: true)
  IO.puts " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C, CTRL+C"

  Task.start_link(fn -> wait_for_messages end)

  render conn, "index.html"
end
```

Comment: Now I have no error but function wait_for_messages is not working as it should. It need to wait for message and to print when receive it but it not working.

Comment: @MišelAdemi What happens if you `require Logger` and use `Logger.info(" [x] Received #{payload}")` instead of `IO.puts " [x] Received #{payload}"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Phoenix Channels would be a better fit for this. Send the clients the index.html, then from that client-side application have them join a channel that sends  messages from your AMQP bus (which will broadcast it to all connected clients). That would give your application that functionality in a much more distributed fashion practically for free. Docs are here: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels

As for the IO.puts ... I'm not clear on the purpose of having console output ... a more Elixir-y way to do this would be to have a process doing the AMQP messaging and another process you can start/interact with from an iex console that consumes messages from it and provides an API to stop (e.g. kill) the AMQP processor.

.. but as it stands, relying on that console output limits you to one such interaction at a time ... and web services are by their nature not that sort of thing.